# How to change the title of an event when using captureMessage in Sentry (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, sentry

I'm using Sentry in my Node.js projects for error logging and it's working great. I've also started using Sentry to capture certain events which show up in Sentry with a blue mark as opposed to orange (I believe orange represents errors).

The bit I can't seem to control is the title of the event which always shows up as `Error`. I would like to change this to something more representative of what is happening such as `Message` or `Log` as these events are not errors.

Is this possible? I've been through the Sentry docs but can't seem to find how this can be changed.

What's also weird is that if I set the level to `log` in Node.js, it doesn't seem to be reflecting in Sentry. It always appears as `info`.

```
fastify.sentry.withScope(function(scope) {
    scope.setLevel('log')
    scope.setTransactionName('Create Transaction')
    scope.setExtra('Transaction UUID', uuid)
    scope.setExtra('Merchant ID', merchantId)
    scope.setExtra('Body', body)
    scope.setExtra('Transaction ID', transactionId)
    fastify.sentry.captureMessage(uuid)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Sentry documentation is driving me mad. It's crammed with guides on how to enhance the aggregation of amplified platform envelope events and whatever but good luck finding an API reference or how to do simple basic things.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by pure fluke.

If I do the following, Sentry changes the title:

```
fastify.sentry.withScope(function(scope) {
    scope.setLevel('log')
    scope.setTransactionName('Create Transaction')
    scope.setExtra('Transaction UUID', uuid)
    scope.setExtra('Merchant ID', merchantId)
    scope.setExtra('Body', body)
    scope.setExtra('Transaction ID', transactionId)
    fastify.sentry.captureMessage(`Log: ${uuid}`)
})
```

Comment: I'm assuming this will be something similar on the .NET SDK? I'm guessing `SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex, scope => scope.TransactionName = "Custom event title")`?

Comment: setTransactionName wasn't change the title but this line did it for me: ```fastify.sentry.captureMessage(`Log: ${uuid}`)```. What I wanted is the world "Log" in front of entries so I can easily identify them.